# Subscribe to topic issue

Tags: javascript, php, flutter, google-cloud-messaging

hi I'm creating a web app, i'm trying to have the toggle in the website it self if turned on it sends he is subscribed to a topic in firebase. i'm using flutter is there a way I tried searching all over but couldn't grasp it even in the documentation

I tried this way

```
    <button type="button" onclick="subscribeTokenToTopic">Tag VIP User</button>
```

```
 importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js");
    importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js");

  const config = {
    apiKey: "x",
          authDomain: "x",
          projectId: "x",
          storageBucket: "x",
          messagingSenderId: "x",
          appId: "x",
          measurementId: "x")
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);



      function subscribeTokenToTopic(token, topic) {
        await FirebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('weather');

      }
```

Comment: Your code is javascript?

Comment: You tagged your question as being about `[flutter]` and `[php]`, yet the only code you shared is in JavaScript. To maximize the chances of somebody here being able to help, I recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question based on that guidance in your question by clicking the `edit` link under it.

Comment: I believe there is nothing todo with `[flutter]` on this question, can you confirm nasser?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to subscribe and unsubscribe Cloud Messaging's topic

```dart
///Subscribe to topic
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('weather');

///Unsubscribe from topic
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic('weather');
```

You can find more details here
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#subscribing-to-topics

Comment: i have tried using a similar method didn't word i used a button in my website which is linked to a function  with on click function and it gives me subcribetokentotopic is not defined at html button element

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on [subscribing to FCM topics in a web app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic), shows that this is only possible through the (server-side) Admin SDKs for Node, Java, Python, Go, and C#. It is explicitly not possible to subscribe to an FCM topic directly from client-side JavaScript SDK.